# Show flat list in a tree structure where children have more than one parent?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, algorithm, debugging, tree

I'm a newbie in Javascript and a beginner in programming.  I have a list of "step" objects with a choice/solution field. This choice/solution field references another object in the list. I would like to create a tree hierarchy from this list based on this field.

[ Here is the array file i would like to restructure like a tree :

```
$scope.nodes = {
  "story": {
    "step" : [
      {
        "title": "Begin",
        "id": "0",
        "type": "MultipleChoice",
        "description": "Yo, bro it's the start of the adventure !",
        "choice": [
          {
          "nextStepId": "1",
          "#text": "You was born as a troll, no luck in life. :'("
        }]
      },
      {
        "title": "Choice",
        "id": "1",
        "type": "MultipleChoice",
        "description": "It's time to take your life back, and choice what you should do !",
          "choice": [
        {
          "nextStepId": "1001",
          "#text": "Take an apple"
        },
        {
          "nextStepId": "4",
          "#text": "Suicide"
        },
        {
          "nextStepId": "1001",
          "#text": "You use a coin to know what to do"
        }
        ]
      },
      {
        "title": "Riddle",
        "id": "4",
        "type": "Riddle",
        "description": "What is the best way to suicide ?",
        "solution": {
        "nextStep": "1000",
          "#text": "think"
        }
      },
      {
        "title": "you are dead",
        "id": "1000",
        "type": "End",
        "win": "true",
        "description": "Nice, you are dead finally !"
      },
      {
        "title": "you are alive",
        "id": "1001",
        "type": "End",
        "win": "false",
        "description": "Damn, you are still alive !"

      }
    ]
}
}
```

and here is what I did so far :

```
$scope.tree = function tree() {
  var map = {}, node, roots = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i += 1) {
    node = nodes.story.step[i];
    map[node.id] = i;
    if (node.id !== "0") {
      switch (node.type) {
        case ("MultipleChoice"):
          for (var j = 0; i < node.choice.length; j += 1)
          nodes[map[node.id]].choice[j].nextStepId[j].push(node);
          break;
        case ("Riddle"):
          nodes[map[node.id]].solution.nextStep[j].push(node);
          break;
        case ("End"):
        //TO DO
      }
    }
    else {
      roots.push(node);
    }
  }
}(nodes)
```

(Notice that a children (choice/solution) can have more than one parent, and that 'choice' can be either an array or one element.)

Apparently, i am doing something wrong. choice is 'undefined'

Can you please correct me?? I can't it figure out. I would preferably like to keep my own code to learn from my mistakes, but feel free if you have something else to suggest.

Thank you so much

Comment: Is this question different than these two from you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37743204/constructing-a-tree-from-a-json-array-in-javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37716801/constructing-a-hierarchical-tree-from-a-json-array

Comment: Yes, it is. The constraints are different

Comment: Stop repeating the same question! Update one not create a new one over and over. You just asked the same one again a few minutes ago and deleted it after clarification was asked for. That is not how to use this site

Comment: I deleted all of them. I am new to this site and I learn from my mistakes. What impresses me the most in you is that you were eager to point out this fact, without any intention to help whatsover...

Answer (score 0):

I would code this differently. Using `ng-switch` is very useful here. Then you can store the current step in a variable and decide in `ng-switch` what you'd like to show (multiple choices, Riddle or end).

If you'd like to prevent the user from cheating you have to add the solution check at server-side because your model is readable in the browser console and the user could check the right answer before clicking.

The only part of you app that isn't clear to me it the 'riddle' question. So this is maybe not like you want it. But that shouldn't be difficult to modify.

Please have a look at the demo below or at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/1jyLdq8b/).

```js
angular.module('demoApp', [])
    .controller('mainCtrl', MainCtrl);

function MainCtrl($scope) {
 var vm = this;
    
    var nodes = {
        "story": {
            "step": [{
                "title": "Begin",
                "id": "0",
                "type": "MultipleChoice",
                "description": "Yo, bro it's the start of the adventure !",
                "choice": [{
                    "nextStepId": "1",
                    "#text": "You was born as a troll, no luck in life. :'("
                }]
            }, {
                "title": "Choice",
                "id": "1",
                "type": "MultipleChoice",
                "description": "It's time to take your life back, and choice what you should do !",
                "choice": [{ // missing [ here
                    "nextStepId": "1001",
                    "#text": "Take an apple"
                }, {
                    "nextStepId": "4",
                    "#text": "Suicide"
                }, {
                    "nextStepId": "1001",
                    "#text": "You use a coin to know what to do"
                }]
            }, {
                "title": "Riddle",
                "id": "4",
                "type": "Riddle",
                "description": "What is the best way to suicide ?",
                "solution": {
                    "nextStepId": "1000",
                    "#text": "think"
                }
            }, {
                "title": "you are dead",
                "id": "1000",
                "type": "End",
                "win": true,
                "description": "Nice, you are dead finally !"
            }, {
                "title": "you are alive",
                "id": "1001",
                "type": "End",
                "win": false,
                "description": "Damn, you are still alive !"

            }]
        }
    };

 function getById(id) {
     var node;
        for(var i=0; i<nodes.story.step.length; i++) {
         node = nodes.story.step[i];
            if ( node.id === id ) {
             return node;
            }
        }
    }
 angular.extend(vm, {
     nodes: nodes,
        curStep: nodes.story.step[0],
        next: function(id) {
         vm.curStep = getById(id);
        }
    });
    
 /*
    // too complicated
    $scope.tree = function tree() {
        var map = {},
            node, roots = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < nodes.story.step.length; i++) { // nodes is an object
            //console.log(nodes.story);
            node = nodes.story.step[i];
            console.log(node);
            node.choice.nextStepId = [];
            node.solution.nextStep = [];
            map[node.id] = i;
            if (node.id !== "0") {
                switch (node.type) {
                    case ("MultipleChoice"):
                        for (var j = 0; i < node.choice.length; j += 1)
                            nodes[map[node.choice[j].nextStepId]].choice[j].nextStepId.push(node);
                        break;
                    case ("Riddle"):
                        nodes[map[node.id]].solution.nextStep.push(node);
                }
            } else {
                roots.push(node);
            }
        }
        console.log(JSON.stringify(roots, null, 2));
    }

    $scope.tree();*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl as ctrl">
    <div>
        {{ctrl.curStep.description}}
        <div ng-switch="ctrl.curStep.type">
            <div ng-switch-when="MultipleChoice">
                <div ng-repeat="choice in ctrl.curStep.choice">
                <!--<label>{{choice['#text']}}</label>-->
                    <!--<input type="checkbox" ng-click="ctrl.next(choice.nextStepId)"/>-->
                    <button ng-click="ctrl.next(choice.nextStepId)">
                    {{choice['#text']}}
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div ng-switch-when="Riddle">
                <a href="#" ng-click="ctrl.next(ctrl.curStep.solution.nextStepId)">{{ctrl.curStep.solution['#text']}}</a>
        </div>
        <div ng-switch-when="End">
            Game Over! <strong>{{ctrl.curStep.win ? 'You\'ve won!': 'You\'ve lost'}}</strong>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- just for debugging <pre>{{ctrl.nodes | json: 2}}</pre>-->
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your contribution, I appreciate it alot !! Riddle is a question that the user have to answer by submitting the answer. But I still don't see how to construct the tree? My inital algo was meant to only restructure the json array. Please can you update it... Thanks!!